# UPDATE SQL database with multiple SETs?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to update my SQL database with multiple SETs. What I'm trying to achieve is to update a customer record in a table. For example, the customer might change their address.

Here is my code:

```
            <?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
               if (!$con){
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
               }
                   mysql_select_db("floras", $con);
                   for ($i=count($_POST['id']); $i--;) {
                           $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
                           $custf = $_POST['fname'];
                           $custs = $_POST['sname'];
                           $custe = $_POST['email'];
                           $custp = $_POST['phone'];
                           $custm = $_POST['mobile'];
                           $custa1 = $_POST['add1'];
                           $custa2 = $_POST['add2'];
                           $custt = $_POST['town'];
                           $custc = $_POST['county'];
                           $custpc = $_POST['postc'];
                       $sql="UPDATE tbl_customer SET
                              customer_forename=$custf,
                              customer_surname=$custs,
                              customer_email=$custe,
                              customer_phone=$custp,
                              customer_mobile=$custm,
                              customer_address1=$custa1,
                              customer_address2=$custa2,
                              customer_town=$custt,
                              customer_county=$custc,
                              customer_postcode=$custpc
                            WHERE customer_id=$id";
                }
                if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
                   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            mysql_close($con); 
            ?>
```

Obviously, this has all been sent via a post and the $_POST variables have been set to another variable before the SQL command.

When I open the page, the error I get is:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, customer_address2=Address 2, customer_town=Town, customer_county=County, cust' at line 1

Any help?

Thank you all!

Comment: Your strings should be wrapped with quotes, also this illegal character should not be there `>` `customer_surname`

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate user input into SQL statements. Use prepared statements instead to prevent you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose string variables within single quotes.your update query will look like :

```
$sql="UPDATE tbl_customer SET customer_forename='$custf', 
customer_surname='$custs',
customer_email='$custe', customer_phone='$custp',customer_mobile='$custm',
customer_address1='$custa1', customer_address2='$custa2',
customer_town='$custt', 
customer_county='$custc', customer_postcode='$custpc' 
WHERE customer_id=$id";
```

Comment: @Scruffs you are welcome and on a side note please dont use mysql_* functions as they are depracated.happy coding. :)

Comment: @Scruffs you can also mark this answer as answered and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in your query. remove `>` from query and add `'` single quotes

```
$sql="UPDATE tbl_customer SET `customer_forename`='$custf',
`customer_surname`='$custs',
`customer_email`='$custe', `customer_phone`='$custp',`customer_mobile`='$custm',
`customer_address1`='$custa1', `customer_address2`='$custa2',
`customer_town`='$custt',
`customer_county`='$custc', `customer_postcode`='$custpc' 
 WHERE `customer_id`='$id'"
```

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately as a stack newbie the > were meant to be block quote indents.

Comment: welcome..i have make changes into you query . you can use it :)

Comment: The backticks around the column names are not needed (just adds noise to the code)

Answer (score 0):

remove > from field name >customer_surname

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `>` symbols from fields and pass values within `'` single quotes. Something like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE tbl_customer SET customer_forename='$custf', customer_surname='$custs', customer_email='$custe', customer_phone='$custp', customer_mobile='$custm', customer_address1='$custa1', customer_address2='$custa2', customer_town='$custt', customer_county='$custc', customer_postcode='$custpc' WHERE customer_id='$id'"; }
```